# How to get Sub-Training and Sub-Test from cross validation in Caret

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret

I am using Caret and have divided my data into training(75%) and test (25%) sets. Now I am running 10-Fold CV on training data. I fit the following model:

```
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
output <- train(Species~., data=iris, trControl=train_control, method="rpart2")
```

Question 1:
Is the accuracy shown by output an average Sub-Test set or Sub-Training i.e. (10% of Training data or 90% of Training data)

Question 2: 
How can I view the accuracy of both sets for each folds i.e. accuracy of Sub-Test and  Sub-Training set for each of 10-Folds

Answer (score 16):

So using 10-fold CV will split the data into 10 different sets of roughly the same size. The model is fit on 90% and the remaining 10% is used to estimate accuracy. This process continues "round robin" 9 more times.

The accuracy is the average of the 10 holdouts for each tuning value. For example:

```
> set.seed(1)
> train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10,
+                               savePredictions = TRUE) 
> output <- train(Species~., data=iris, trControl=train_control, method="rpart2")
note: only 2 possible values of the max tree depth from the initial fit.
 Truncating the grid to 2 .
```

There is a sub-object that has the hold-out estimates of accuracy for each fold, and averaging these gets you the reported value (the ones shown here are for the optimal value of Cp):

```
> output$resample
        Accuracy Kappa Resample
    1  0.8666667   0.8   Fold01
    2  0.9333333   0.9   Fold02
    3  1.0000000   1.0   Fold03
    4  0.9333333   0.9   Fold04
    5  0.9333333   0.9   Fold05
    6  0.8000000   0.7   Fold06
    7  1.0000000   1.0   Fold07
    8  1.0000000   1.0   Fold08
    9  0.9333333   0.9   Fold09
    10 0.9333333   0.9   Fold10
    > mean(output$resample$Accuracy)
[1] 0.9333333
> getTrainPerf(output)
  TrainAccuracy TrainKappa method
1     0.9333333        0.9 rpart2
```

There is little value in getting predictions on the 90% each time. Since the same data is used to build the model, the predictions can be extremely optimistic (which is the motivation for using cross-validation in the first place).

If you want to see where the estimates in `output$resample` were created:

```
> ## For the model associated with optimal Cp value, here is the predictions on the 
> ## first fold that was held-out
> first_holdout <- subset(output$pred, Resample == "Fold01")
> head(first_holdout)
        pred        obs rowIndex maxdepth Resample
1     setosa     setosa        6        2   Fold01
2     setosa     setosa       27        2   Fold01
3     setosa     setosa       31        2   Fold01
4     setosa     setosa       36        2   Fold01
5     setosa     setosa       45        2   Fold01
6 versicolor versicolor       67        2   Fold01
```

If we get the accuracy for this set:

```
> postResample(first_holdout$pred, first_holdout$obs)
 Accuracy     Kappa 
0.7666667 0.6500000
```

Max

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!. You have really helped me in getting to this point. Can you please share a link which gives the list of all sub-objects of the output?

Comment: It may not be 100% up to date, but look at the `Value` section of `?train`

Comment: Thanks I got the list at this location http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/extractPrediction